# What does the [0] do that is passed at the end of the filter method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I got this code while doing a udemy course but didn't get it correctly .
What dose the [0] passed at the end of the filter method do and what is its use?

```
let getUser = this.globalRoom.filter((userId) => {
  return userId.id === id;
})[0]
```

Comment: What does `[0]` normally do when you use it with an array?

Answer (score 0):

As `filter` returns an array that contains only items that pass the callback check, the `[0]` gives you the first item in such list.

**However**, this is an antipattern, because the right tool for the job here is [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), and here is why:

- `filter` keeps looping over the whole array, even if you are interested only in its first result
- `find` returns exactly the first result, and it stops looping the array, without needing to access its first index

Accordingly, this is a much better way to do the exact same thing:

```
let getUser = this.globalRoom.find((userId) => {
  return userId.id === id;
});
```

And you should check that `getUser` returns a value, because as `filter` could be an empty array, so that accessing its index `0` would return undefined, `find` also returns `undefined` if no satisfying condition is matched once.